# How do I get the string after a specific substring of a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I extract PART of a specific string from a huge chunk of ugly strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294520/how-do-i-extract-part-of-a-specific-string-from-a-huge-chunk-of-ugly-strings)

String:

```
https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/33126.json
```

I need the number 33126.

What's the optimal way to extract this number?

Comment: de-ja-vu?  i think i've seen this question before

Comment: you are asking the same question....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since that is a path/url, use  [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx):

```
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

I would prefer `Path`, but if you want to use the `Uri` class instead, you can also use this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/33126.json");
string lastSegment = uri.Segments.Last();
string name = lastSegment.Substring(0, lastSegment.IndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: Well it's a URL rather than a path as such... `Path.GetFileNameWithoutException` *may* work, but I think I'd be looking at URL classes...

Comment: yes, this is a URL, will Path work without any issues?!

Comment: yup, it wouldnt let me for 10 mins! now i got it :)

Comment: tht's not an **optimal** way to do it..it's just another way around..

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It: What's the _optimal_ way? Imho it's an easy, conscise, readable and efficient way. It works on unix and on windows for urls and for directory paths and is easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for regular expressions.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/(\d+).json");

        Match match = regex.Match("https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/33126.json");

        foreach(Group group in match.Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
        }
```